# replace all comma seperated numbers to dot seperated numbers in string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Assume there are string with numbers, for instance,
`test() test 12,01% test (12,4)  12.3 s 2 some other text, other text, 2,text`

I need to replace numbers with comma to the same numbers with dot and do not change anything else. So string would become

`test() test 12.01% test (12.4)  12.3 s 2 some other text, other text, 2,text`

I tried something like this:

```
var newstr = str.replace(/^\d+,\d+$/g, "\1.\2");
```

or
    var newstr = str.replace(^\d*\,?\d+$/g, "\1.\2");

- I think this should match any number with comma: ^\d*\,?\d+$

Comment: `/(\d+),(\d+)/g`

Comment: `var newstr = str.replace( /(\d),(\d)/g, "\1.\2");` Like this? You don't need to add anchors nor quantifiers, but you have to define capture groups.

Comment: Dollars not backslashes in the replaced string

Comment: @Max: I always forget that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this and capture 2 groups:

[`(\d+),(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/kIPzez/1)

**Explanation**

- **Group 1**: capture 1 or more digits`(\d+)`
- Match a comma `,`
- **Group 2**: capture 1 or more digits`(\d+)`

```js
var str = "test() test 12,01% test (12,4)  12.3 s 2 some other text, other text, 2,text";
var newstr = str.replace(/(\d+),(\d+)/g, "$1.$2", ".");
console.log(newstr);
```

Comment: You don't need to match the whole number to replace just the comma.

Comment: @tiagodws That is correct. In this case [`(\d+),(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/kIPzez/1) is slightly faster than [`(\d),(\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/DF3dH2/1/).

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the explanation! Just for future reference, where did you find this information?

Comment: if a string contains large integers, the result may be different.

Comment: `\b(\d+),(\d)` is faster but that's assuming the number isn't preceded by a letter or underscore

Answer (score 2):

```
yourString.replace(/(\d),(\d)/g, "$1.$2")
```

This will match every comma between numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var newstr = str.replace( /\b(\d+),(\d+)\b/g, "$1.$2");
```

The purpose of having the `\b` word boundaries in there is to make sure that you don’t accidentally match numbers that are adjacent to letters. Since part of your example has the text `2,text`, it appears that there is potential for some unusual text such as `2,1text` to show up, in which case you probably *don’t* intend to replace the comma with a period.

Comment: Not quite, you use `$1.$2` in the replaced string (JS thinks of backslashes in strings weirdly; so for RegExes it asks you to use that format in the replaced version)

Comment: this doesn't match the first occurence i.e. str = "2,3 test e 2, mis 2.3  4,54 tes"

Comment: I don't think (for the current requirements) you have to check what is before or after the digits.

Comment: @MarouenMhiri You’re right - thanks. Updated my answer to include situations where the number occurs at the beginning or and of the string.

Comment: The fourth bird has the best answer

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte  yes - but just based on the example which includes the unusual-looking “ 2,text” it seems that there could be cases where being more specific would be helpful for this situation.